# Table of contents in markdown for Nikola

Tags: nikola

I've been using Sphinx for my personal website for the past years and realized that I more have a blog with posts and few pages and did the conversion to Nikola in the past days. I also took the opportunity to switch to Markdown as I use it with R and Stack Overflow and everywhere else as well.

I have set in my Sphinx theme to have a local table of contents in the sidebar. There are a handful of very long (over 10k words) posts that would benefit from a local table of contents. I saw that the Nikola manual is written in reST and uses the `contents` directive. I would like to use that also in those posts.

I could convert these few posts back to reST and use the contents directive, but I'd like to avoid that. Can this be accomplished somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Using `[TOC]` which is a feature of an extension enabled by default. My firts answer was an misinterpretation of your question.

**Firts answer**

Using Nikola, may be you are interested in "archive" option. This is a default page that include all your posts (optional, this is grouped by date). Example in my blog: https://www.cosmoscalibur.com/archive.html .

Comment: I already have the archive. I was more interested in a local table of contents for the article.

Comment: I misinterpreted your question. You can use `[TOC]` where you want the table of content of your post.

Answer (score 2):

Nikola uses [Python-Markdown](https://python-markdown.github.io/) by default. It supports a [TOC extension](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/toc/) that one can enable in the `conf.py`. Then one can use a `[TOC]` marker anywhere in the document to get a local table of contents.

Comment: As an additional note: 

To enable the TOC extension in Nikola, you need to add `markdown.extensions.toc` to your config.

For example: 

```python
MARKDOWN_EXTENSIONS = ['markdown.extensions.toc']
```

After that, using `[TOC]` works for me.